# array of inputs separate them

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of inputs and I would like to separate them depending on id, I want all starts with different names:

```
var documents = $('[data-document]');
documents
init[8]
   0: input#fistID
   1: input#firstTitle
   2: input#firstSize
   3: input#secondID
   4: input#secondTitle
   5: input#secondSize
```

how can I get all the elements from my array whose id starts with "first"??

Comment: According to jquery doc... http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for value prefixes for that:

```
var first = $('[data-document][id^=first]');
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't technically have an array, you have a jQuery object which happens to behave a lot like an array. You can use [`jQuery.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter an existing jQuery object and return a new jQuery object containing only the elements that match your selector.

```
var documents = $('[data-document]');

var filteredDocuments = documents.filter('[id^=first]');
```

Answer (score 1):

As Ouroborus explained, you could use the CSS attribute selector.

But just in case you need to do it with JS (this is just one option of many *if performance's not an issue*):

```
documents.filter(function(i, elem){
    return elem.attr('id').indexOf('first') == 0;
});
```

Comment: This won't work as expected because `documents` is a jquery object with its own `filter()` method. You'd have to first convert the jquery object to a plain array to use this method.

Comment: @Soviut according to jQuery's documentation, the filter callback accepts a  selector (like the one you used), **a function (like the one I used *[edited the index that was missing]*)**, DOM elements to match or a jQuery object to match.